# YouTube V3 Create Broadcast

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to create a broadcast using YouTube's v3 API. My request looks like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ******************" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "  {\"snippet\":{\"title\":\"Hello\", \"scheduledStartTime\":\"2014-01-30T00:00:00.000Z\", \"scheduledEndTime\":\"2014-01-31T00:00:00.000Z\"},\"status\":{\"privacyStatus\":\"public\"}}" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet,status
```

But the response I get from google is this:

```
{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
 {
   "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
   "reason": "liveBroadcastForbidden",
   "message": "Request is not authorized"
 }
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Request is not authorized"
}
}
```

I can confirm that the access token I am passing is correct. 
Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Livestreaming API is only available to partners right now. It will be more widely available later.
If you have gotten the granted access, you should enable YouTube APIs from [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). It looks like you haven't enabled them.

Comment: I have access as a partner. And I have Youtube APIs accessible for the API console. Just realized that I had created a client id for installed applications instead of web applications. does that matter?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I was actually looking at the code written by you. I am trying to do something similar in Ruby btw. I am still stuck. I have re-checked everything and made another call to create broadcast. This time I get this error {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}

Comment: Livestreaming is another access level, which is only available to few selected partners, not every partner. Will update when it's more widely available.

Comment: How can one be a partner ? I really really need that API.

Comment: Recently YouTube announced that anyone in good standing and have more than 1000 subscribers in their channels can request access to live streaming.